# In MVC 3,Drop down list how to eliminate default NULL value and display the list retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In drop down box it is taking Default as NULL value even though I didn't set any NULL value when it is coming from database. Currently my drop down looks like on top NULL value then followed by values which I set.

I want to delete that default NULL value and display "Design" as my default value in drop down list.

Below is the Cshtml code which I use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Document.Phase, "NamedPropertySelectList", 
            new { SelectList = Model.Lookups.Phases.ToSelectList(), tabindex = tabindex++ })
```

Comment: You need to show the Editor Template (NamedPropertySelectList). And is  the value of `Document.Phase` = "Design"?

Comment: Yes Value of Document.phase="Design"

Comment: And does one of the options you generate have `value="Design" (you also need to show your custom editor template)